# Warning: mysqli_fetch_field_direct(): Field offset is invalid for resultset

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using PHP 7 trying to get a CSV file from data stored in a table which fields are
"id", "name", "code", "category", "price", "stock_count"

things are fine but getting warnings like

> **Warning**:  mysqli_fetch_field_direct(): Field offset is invalid for resultset in **C:\xampp\htdocs\php_csv_file_export\php_csv_export_method1.php** on line **8**

> **Warning**:  mysqli_fetch_field_direct(): Field offset is invalid for resultset in **C:\xampp\htdocs\php_csv_file_export\php_csv_export_method1.php** on line **8**

Code is below

```
<?php
    $con= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "phpp");
    $result=mysqli_query($con,"select * from top");
    $num_column=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $csv_header = '';
    for($i=0;$i<$num_column;$i++) 
    {
        if(isset(mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result,$i)->name))
        {
            $csv_header .= '"' . mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result,$i)->name . '",';
        }
    }
    $csv_header .= "\n";
    $csv_row ='';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) 
    {
        for($i=0;$i<$num_column;$i++) 
        {           
            if(isset($row[$i]))
            {
                $csv_row .= '"' . $row[$i] . '",';
            }               
        }
        $csv_row .= "\n";
    }   
    /* Download as CSV File */
    header('Content-type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=toy_csv.csv');
    echo $csv_header . $csv_row;
    exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you are looping the ROWS instead of your colums

```
$num_column=mysqli_num_rows($result); // rows != Columns
```

i think you are looking for http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php and you can do something like :

```
foreach(mysqli_fetch_fields($result) as $field){
  $csv_header .= '"' . $field->name . '",';
  unset($field);
}
```

If you were using a statement, you could do something more like:

```
    $meta = mysqli_stmt_result_metadata($stmt);
    foreach ( mysqli_fetch_field($meta) as $field ) {
       $csv_header .= '"' . $field->name . '",';
       unset($field);
    }
```